# Can one create an online Minecraft world map for Minecraft Realms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-java-edition-realms

As far as I know, Minecraft Realms servers function similarly to other multiplayer servers. I have been playing on a recently closed server that had this useful online function: an online dynamic world map accessible on the web page of the server. It basically is something like Google maps for Minecraft servers - one can see the Minecraft world with all the structures built by players and also there are displayed real-time locations of all online players.

Now I have started this Minecraft Realm server as a replacement for the old one, and I would like to have this online map function.

So, the question is: **is this function avalible even for Minecraft Realms?** If no, is there at least anything similar to this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Realms provides easy access to the multiplayer experience, but that's all. You could see Realms as a singleplayer world, but then for multiple players, similar to the "Open to LAN" option in a singleplayer world.

If you want an online world map, you will have to create or rent a server instead. Some server hosts have this feature readily available, but I think there are also Bukkit/Spigot plug-ins that allow you to do this. Honestly I have little experience with servers, but I can tell you that realms is not what you are looking for if you want an online world map.